# Run python code in cloud without stopping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation, cloud

I have python code that depends on specific libraries like selenium and interaction with google chrome to extract data from the web.

my code works fine but i need a lot of records to do analysis, so i can't leave my computer on, to run the script for a month.

That's why I thought of running the script in a cloud service like aws but I don't have a clear idea of ​​how to do it, because I need the script to not stop

and I would rather not have to pay for it (or at least not that much money)
That said, my code opens a website, looks for a specific text data and saves it in a csv document.

I thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Welcome to SO. IMHO your question is too open. There are many different cloud providers with their own bunch of possibilities to achieve what you want. You should make familiar with the providers and their offerings. Additionally, I highly doubt, that any provider will let you do this free of charge, especially if something is running for a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to check the terms of each cloud service as many do have downtime/restarts on their free tiers.
The kind of task you're describing shouldn't be very resource hungry, so you may be better off setting up your own server using a Raspberry Pi or similar.

Comment: depending on the pricing and how much cloud resources you really need you may be better off by running it on your spare machine if you have one.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, could you give me an explicit example of how you would solve it.

so I could search to learn more about the matter